How to obtain the random slope for each participant when I fit a GAMM using mgcv?
Our dataset includes approximately 300 participants.
We measured testosterone levels three times for each participant, at ages 12, 14, and 16.
We aim to use a generalized additive mixed model (GAMM) to calculate each participant's rate of change in testosterone levels with age.
We constructed the following model:
model_ageBYsex_T <- gam(Testosterone ~ sex +
  s(Age, bs = "cr", k = 4) + 
  s(Age, by = sex, k = 4, bs = 'fs') +
  s(Age, PID, bs = "re") +
  s(PID, bs = "re"),
  data = df.hormoneMF, method = "REML", select = TRUE)

where PID indicates the participant ID.
From my understanding, the term s(Age, PID, bs = "re") can capture the rate of change in testosterone levels with age for each participant (i.e., the random slope).
The term s(PID, bs = "re") represents the random intercept for each participant.
Could you please confirm if my interpretation is correct?
Additionally, I am aware that the ranef function does not extract random effects in a GAMM. Could you advise on how to use the coef function to extract the random slope for each PID?
Thank you for your assistance.

You can use the {marginaleffects} package to pull out any type of contrast / conditional / marginal prediction that you are after when modelling with {mgcv}. Here is an introductory post to get you started, and here is a deeper dive into {marginaleffects} functionality
